# GLM Equation Interpretation

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, predictive-models

I have developed a glm Poisson model in R and would like to extract the formula so that I can do the computation in another software language. When I write out the equation I am getting different values from the `predict` function in R and the math I do manually.

```
summary(model1)

Call:
glm(formula = time ~ dayPart+ weekPart + NumberOfCustomers, 
    family = poisson(link = log), data = trainDf)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.0077  -0.6974  -0.1732   0.6231   2.4361  

Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)          5.471287   0.018404 297.291  < 2e-16 ***
DAY_PARTNight        0.177905   0.015721  11.317  < 2e-16 ***
DAY_PARTEvening      0.106609   0.020109   5.302 1.15e-07 ***
DAY_PARTAfternoon    0.082161   0.016076   5.111 3.21e-07 ***
WEEK_DESCWEEKEND     0.083837   0.012819   6.540 6.16e-11 ***
NumberOfCustomers    0.069795   0.002081  33.545  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1405.299  on 69  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:   81.949  on 64  degrees of freedom
AIC: Inf

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 3
```

For example I have this row

`Morning WEEKDAY   1 (customer)    255 11.463557 (prediction)`

calculate:

```
exp(5.47)+ (0)(1) + (0)(1) + exp(0.069795)*1 = 238

exp(5.47) - the exp of the intercept since I used a log link function
(0)(1) - The coefficient for Weekday since this is the base for WEEK_DESC
(0)(1) - Since morning is base for time of day categorical variable
exp(0.069795) - slope for number of customers.
```

What is wrong where I'm getting differences between the predict function result of 255 and my math where I calculate 238?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to solve for the (entire) linear predictor first, then exponentiate.  Consider:

```
exp(5.471287 + 0.177905*0 + 0.106609*0 + 0.082161*0 + 0.083837*0 + 0.069795*1)
# [1] 254.9537
```

You are summing the exponentiation of `5.47` and the exponentiation of `0.069795`, instead of exponentiating the sum of `5.47 + 0.069795`.  Because exponentiation is a nonlinear transformation, $f(x+y)\ne f(x)+f(y)$ (cf., [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality)).

Because this is a Poisson GLiM with a log link, the exponentiation of the intercept is the expected value when all covariates are zero (and the categorical variables are at the reference level).  In addition, the exponentiation of a coefficient yields the multiplicative factor by which the expected value will increase with a one-unit increase in the covariate.  Thus, in this case you could equivalently do:

```
exp(5.471287) * exp(0.069795*1)
# [1] 254.9537
```

or,

```
exp(5.471287) * exp(0.069795)^1
# [1] 254.9537
```

But note that you have *multiplied* here, not added.